# Kusto translation ID to Name

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am new to kusto query and i need to translate app id to name of app.
if i list just everything i get back lot of information and one of them is clientId - xxxxxx then i do a query where i list unique user per school with user ID. in other words i can see user per specific school per clientid (app). We have several apps users can use. I would like to extend this and do a translation that i know that this client ID is equal to this app from app registration.
Any ideas how could i achieve that?

```
customEvents 
| where timestamp > ago(30d) and name == "SignInComplete"
| summarize dcount(tostring(customDimensions.ClientID)) by tostring(customDimensions.SchoolID), tostring(customDimensions.UserID)
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Please edit the question to include sample data, and expected output.

Comment: I want to achieve that i have in AAD app registration with name testxx with app id xx-xxx-xxx and in KUSTO i can see this ID but not a name of app, and i would like to translate app ID to appName

Comment: I don't think you can do this in Kusto itself. you need to write some custom code around that which queries Kusto and also has access to your AAD tenant to fetch the info via API from there

Comment: Kusto allows you query and manipulate data that you already have. If you don't have the data (e.g. mapping from AppId to AppName), then you'll need to get it from another place, like @silent suggested.

Comment: I think in Kusto i can use Datatable where easily where i can define appid:string and appName: string and make my own table..Just dont know how to make it work ;/

Comment: In this case use the "lookup" operator

Answer (score 0):

```
SigninLogs
| extend AppName = case(AppId == "1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894", "Global PowerShell",
AppId == "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory",
AppId == "00000009-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", "Microsoft.Azure.AnalysisServices",
AppId == "00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", "Microsoft.Azure.Workflow",
AppId == "0f698dd4-f011-4d23-a33e-b36416dcb1e6", "Microsoft Office Client Service",
AppId == "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", "Microsoft.Exchange",
AppId == "00000007-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", "Microsoft.ExchangeOnlineProtection",
AppId == "00000004-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", "Microsoft.Lync",
AppId == "d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c", "Microsoft Office",
AppId == "00000006-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", "Microsoft.Office365Portal",
AppId == "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", "Microsoft.SharePoint",
AppId == "4345a7b9-9a63-4910-a426-35363201d503", "O365 Suite UX",
AppId == "a0c73c16-a7e3-4564-9a95-2bdf47383716", "Office 365 Shell", 
AppId == "89bee1f7-5e6e-4d8a-9f3d-ecd601259da7", "Office 365 Shell Suite",
AppId == "e48d4214-364e-4731-b2b6-47dabf529218", "Skype Web","")
```